# Powershell cannot bind parameter ForegroundColor

Tags: powershell

I have created the following Powershell script which I hope to use to copy files to a network share.

```
function Copy-Deploy
{
 param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Path to scripts")]
  [Alias("pth")]
  [string]$ScriptPath,

  [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Deployment script filename")]
  [Alias("dep")]
  [string]$PowershellDeploymentScript,

  [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="MSI filename")]
  [Alias("m")]
  [string]$MSI,

  [Parameter(Position=3,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Filename of the MSBuild script (.btdfproj)")]
  [Alias("msb")]
  [string]$MSBuildScript,

  [Parameter(Position=4,HelpMessage="UNC path to target server folder")]
  [Alias("server")]
  [string]$TargetServerPath

  )

 $ErrorActionPreference="Stop"

 #Step 1 : copy the MSI, .btdfproj script and control powershell script to the remote server
 Write-Host " Going to enter the mis script block"
 $misScript =
 {
    Write-Host " Path+Filename = {0}({1})" -f $ScriptPath, $PowershellDeploymentScript
    Write-Host " Going to copy files" 
    Write-Host " ScriptPath = $ScriptPath"
    Write-Host " PowershellDeploymentScript = $PowershellDeploymentScript"
    Write-Host " MSI = $MSI"
    Write-Host " MSBuildScript = $MSBuildScript"
    Write-Host " TargetServerPath = $TargetServerPath"


    Copy-Item -Path "$ScriptPath" + "$PowershellDeploymentScript" -Destination "$TargetServerPath"
    Copy-Item -Path "$ScriptPath" + "$MSI" -Destination "$TargetServerPath"
    Copy-Item -Path "$ScriptPath" + "$MSBuildScript" -Destination "$TargetServerPath"
 }
 Invoke-Command -scriptblock $misScript

 #Step2 : Execute the powershell script ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1 remotely on the target server
 #using syntax... invoke-command -computer $MachineName -command { $TargetServerPath + ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1 }" 

}
```

I run this script from the Powershell ISE with the following line:

```
Copy-Deploy "C:\Builds\3\x.Int.MIS\SupportBTDF\Sources\x.Int.MIS\Dev\V1.0\Src\Solutions\MIS\x.Int.MIS.Deployment\" "ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1" "bin\debug\x.Int.MIS-3.0.0.msi" "x.Int.MIS.Deployment.btdfproj" "\\d-vasbiz01\BizTalkDeployment"
```

I then get the following error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'ForegroundColor'. Cannot convert value "C:\Builds\3\x.Int.MIS\SupportBTDF\Sources\x.Int.MIS\Dev\V1.0\Src\Solutions\MIS\x.Int.MIS.Deployment\,ExecuteBizTalkAppMSI.ps1" to type "System.ConsoleColor" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Black, DarkBlue, DarkGreen, DarkCyan, DarkRed, DarkMagenta, DarkYellow, Gray, DarkGray, Blue, Green, Cyan, Red, Magenta, Yellow, White".At C:\Builds\3\x.Int.MIS\SupportBTDF\Sources\x.Int.MIS\Dev\V1.0\Src\Solutions\MIS\x.Int.MIS.Deployment\CopyDeployScriptThenExecute.ps1:79 char:16
```

Could anyone please tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The line :

```
Write-Host " Path+Filename = {0}({1})" -f $ScriptPath, $PowershellDeploymentScript
```

is the problem.

Write it like this:

```
Write-Host (" Path+Filename = {0}({1})" -f $ScriptPath, $PowershellDeploymentScript)
```

The `-f` was being taken as the `-ForegroundColor` parameter than the string format operator.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the message in parens. You can also use variable expansion and embed the variables without using the -format operator (like you did in other write-host calls):

```
Write-Host " Path+Filename = $ScriptPath($PowershellDeploymentScript)"
```

Comment: Thanks Shay. I never had much luck with using a + to concatenate string but maybe I was getting that problem when using them at the right hand side of the equals sign