# System.Management.Automation.SetValueInvocationException occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll

Tags: c#, powershell, automation

When I run my this C# code, it gives me following error.

CODE:

```cs
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace.Open();

RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command command = new Command("ps\\script.ps1");
string StorageName = "appstorage";
command.Parameters.Add("Name", StorageName.ToLower());

pipeline.Commands.Add(command);
pipeline.Invoke();

runspace.Close();
```

> ERROR: 'System.Management.Automation.SetValueInvocationException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
>
> Exception setting "ForegroundColor": "Cannot convert null to type "System.ConsoleColor" due to enumeration values that are not valid. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Black,DarkBlue,DarkGreen,DarkCyan,DarkRed,DarkMagenta,DarkYellow,Gray,DarkGray,Blue,Green,Cyan,Red,Magenta,Yellow,White"."

Comment: Are (were) you running that in a headless/non-interactive environment such as from SQLAgent?

Comment: Sucks that this has no answer as I am having the exact same issue. @JoshuaDrake I am not running it in a headless environment.

Comment: I see this link: https://sqlserverpowershell.com/2011/11/01/consolecolor-error-in-powershell-job-step-in-sql-server/ but that seems to apply to headless environments only. The interesting thing is my script works fine if I run it from the powershell itself. Only breaks when I run it from C#.

Comment: And this thread mentions the issue too but he says he has "NFI what that issue was about": http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1759125

Comment: @nhouser9 powershell has the obvious output of the screen or command window in which it is executing, in the case of C# making the call the output may be being redirected.

Comment: Any calls to write, clear, or possibly even parameter values of -f see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11719556/19308 can cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Script works fine in console but I get the same message calling it from C#.

At least in my case, the error is generated by a CLS command included in script. The runspace created to execute PowerShell do not have a screen to be cleared so CLS call fails. After comment the line with CLS command, the script is executed correctly from C#.